# truth trees - logical equivalence

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm wondering how to test whether or not two arguments are logically equivalent or not by using the tree method.

Example:

1) $\neg \forall x(Lxa → Lax) $

2) $\exists x(Lxa ∧ \neg Lax) $

I have already checked that they're true using rules of inference, but I'm not sure how to do it on a truth tree.

Comment: You can split the problem, verifying : (i) $¬∀x(Lxa→Lax) \to ∃x(Lxa∧¬Lax)$ and (ii) $∃x(Lxa∧¬Lax) \to ¬∀x(Lxa→Lax)$. For (i) you have to build the truth tree starting with : $¬∀x(Lxa→Lax), ¬∃x(Lxa∧¬Lax)$. The same for (ii).

Comment: I don't quite understand how I'd set up the tree for each case. What would be the predicates and what would be the conclusion, and what does negating the second sentence mean?

Comment: For the rule, you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux#Propositional_logic) as well as [Truth Trees for Propositional Logic](http://legacy.earlham.edu/~peters/courses/log/treeprop.htm).